# MySql LEFT JOIN with COUNT

Tags: mysql, count, left-join

I have two tables, customers and sales. I want to count sales for each customer and create a table of sales per month for each store.

I would like to produce something like;

```
------------------------------
month  |  customers  | sales  |
------------------------------
1/2013 |      5      |   2    |
2/2013 |      21     |   9    |
3/2013 |      14     |   4    |
4/2013 |      9      |   3    |
```

but I am having trouble getting the sales count to be correct when using the following;

```
SELECT CONCAT(MONTH(c.added), '/', YEAR(c.added)), count(c.id), count(s.id)
FROM customers c
LEFT JOIN sales s 
ON s.customer_id = c.id AND MONTH(c.added) = MONTH(s.added) AND YEAR(c.added) = YEAR(s.added)
WHERE c.store_id = 1
GROUP BY YEAR(c.added), MONTH(c.added);
```

Customers table;

```
-------------------------------
id    |   store_id  | added    |
-------------------------------
1     |      1      |2013-02-01 |
2     |      1      |2013-02-02 |
3     |      1      |2013-03-16 |
```

sales table;

```
---------------------------------
id    |   added    | customer_id |
---------------------------------
1     | 2013-02-18 |     3       |
2     | 2013-03-02 |     2       |
3     | 2013-03-16 |     3       |
```

Can anyone help here?

thanks

Comment: Show the table schema and some sample data for both tables.

Comment: Hi @hims056, i have a customers table; [id, added] and a sales table [id, added, customer_id]. The customers table records when the customer was added to the system, and the sales table records when a customer makes a purchase

Comment: Yes I can see that in your question but show the schema and some sample data. (same as you show your expected output)

Comment: @hims056 I have added the tables, and some data. Does that help?

Comment: @ChristyHerron Go to http://www.sqlfiddle.com/ and put a CREATE TABLE code with some sample data. Then your SELECT, that doesn't work.

Comment: @ChristyHerron Why this condition: "AND MONTH(c.added) = MONTH(s.added) AND YEAR(c.added) = YEAR(s.added)"?

Comment: It looks like your query works just fine: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e2dcf/1

Comment: Hi @Olexa, as Mark points out below, my query only counts sales made in the same month as the customer was added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Updated) The existing query will only count sales made in the same month that the customer was added. Try this, instead:

```
SELECT CONCAT(MONTH(sq.added), '/', YEAR(sq.added)) month_year,
       sum(sq.customer_count), 
       sum(sq.sales_count)
FROM (select s.added, 0 customer_count, 1 sales_count
      from customers c
      JOIN sales s ON s.customer_id = c.id
      WHERE c.store_id = 1
      union all
      select added, 1 customer_count, 0 sales_count
      from customers
      WHERE store_id = 1) sq
GROUP BY YEAR(sq.added), MONTH(sq.added);
```

Comment: thanks @Mark, thats great. You seem to have found the issue with my own query. Unfortunately I cant guarantee that a sale will be made in the same month as the customer was added. Is it possible for you to create the 'more complicated' query? Thank you

Comment: @ChristyHerron: This should return new customers per month, and sales per month, for the specified store - note that the sales_count is grouped on the sales table added date. What leads you to think it is returning too many results? Have you tried checking the results for a specific month against the actual records in the database?

Comment: Thanks @Mark, my mistake, your query works great. Thank you so much, im very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.* , s.sales_count<br>
FROM customers c<br>
LEFT JOIN (SELECT customer_id, count(id) as sales_count FROM sales GROUP BY customer_id) s on c.id=s.customer_id<br>
WHERE c.store_id = 1<br>
```

Comment: Kindly include in your answer as well a brief explanation of why this works or what doesn't work in the OP's code such that this answer remedies the problem. :)