# MYSQL query to count descendants of items by finding its id in a comma separated string

Tags: mysql, group-by, left-join, parent-child, find-in-set

My MYSQL database uses a tree-like system where each item can have an arbitrary number of descendants.  Each item has a regular INT 'parent' column containing its parent as well as a VARCHAR 'parents' column which consists of a comma-separated string containing all of its ancestor's ids.

```
id    parent    parents
-------------------------------
1     0         0
2     1         0,1
3     1         0,1
4     3         0,1,3
```

I need to get a list of all items, each of them with their total number of descendants counted up.  Here is the query I have so far:

```
SELECT items.id AS item_id, 
COUNT(children.id) AS children 
FROM items items 
LEFT JOIN items children ON (items.id IN (children.parents))
```

This just sends back one row, with a child count of 0.  How do I do this properly?

EDIT:

After fixing the query so it appears like this:

```
SELECT 
  i.id AS item_id, 
  COUNT(*) AS children 
FROM 
  items i 
LEFT JOIN 
  items c 
  ON (i.id IN (c.parents))
GROUP BY i.id;
```

the results show the rows, but each has only one child.  This does not reflect the data, presumably something is wrong with the IN statement (FIND_IN_SET does the same thing).

EDIT2:

After changing the IN statement to the following

```
ON LOCATE(i.id, c.parents) > 0
```

item 1 has the correct number of children (3) but the remaining items all show up as having 1 child.  Items 2 and 4 should have 0, and 3 should have 1.

Comment: first, avoid using the same alias multiple times; "children" is used as a table alias and a column alias ; same for "items" alias on "times"; these aliases make query ambiguous

Comment: please post your `CREATE TABLE` statements and some sample data

Comment: This is a really bad schema, I would change the table to use a [Nested Set Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model), with a direct parent column as a back up. You can then run very simple queries to get the descendants count, or any other count you want.

Comment: @superphonic That is very useful.  I am going to need to do a lot of queries up and down the tree, so I might go with that structure instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `GROUP BY items.id` for `COUNT()`to work as intended.

With aliases changed to something less ambiguous:

```
SELECT 
  i.id AS item_id, 
  COUNT(*) AS children 
FROM 
  items i 
LEFT JOIN 
  items c 
  ON FIND_IN_SET(i.id, c.parents) > 0 
WHERE c.id <> i.id
GROUP BY i.id;
```

For more complex COUNT()/GROUP BY examples, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16917167/mysql-left-join-with-count) or [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count). For `FIND_IN_SET()`, nice example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16666401/1503505).

See sqlfiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/25706/3)

Comment: This is a little better, but still not working.  All of the rows show up with 1 child.

Comment: Haha ! VARCHAR 'parents' column, comma-separated I guess? Fixed my answer for the "find id in string" part

Comment: Closer, but not quite.  The top-level item has the correct number of descendants, but all the rest still have 1.

Comment: @IndigoFenix please post your table schema and sample data so we can give a better answer

Comment: @IndigoFenix changed back to FIND_IN_SET, tested it with your sample data, looks OK to me now.